# Simplest way to take a photo in Google Glass Android without using the MediaStroe.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent

Tags: android, android-intent, google-glass

What is the simplest way to take a photo in Glass without using the default camera intent?

```
Intent camera_intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

This intent doesn't work correctly in current 19.1 version so a simple workaround is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good solution that is fairly simple and well written (and designed and tested for Glass) is https://github.com/krazykira/CuXtomCam